# Whats the purpose of using n+1 in this eratosthenes function?

Tags: python, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Here is a simple eratosthenes sieve for prime numbers, which removes the multiples and append them in the empty list of multiples. My question is that if I use `n` instead of `n+1` in both `for` loops the answer comes out the same.

```
def eratosthenes(n):
    multiples = []
    for i in xrange(2, n+1):
        if i not in multiples:
            print i
            for j in xrange(i*i, n+1, i):
                multiples.append(j)
```

returns output like

```
eratosthenes(10)
2
3
5
7
```

while if I replace `n+1` with `n` in both loops the output is still the same:

```
def eratosthenes(n):
    multiples = []
    for i in xrange(2, n):
        if i not in multiples:
            print i
            for j in xrange(i*i, n, i):
                multiples.append(j)
```

returns the same output as above function...

```
eratosthenes(10)
2
3
5
7
```

My question is why we use `n+1` instead of `n`?

Comment: Try `eratosthenes(11)` and compare the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python `range()` and `xrange()` functions, like the Python slice notation, do not include the end value; `xrange(2, 10)` generates 8 numbers from `2` to `9`, **not** 10. `n + 1` makes sure `n` is part of the generated range.

Use `eratosthenes(7)` or `eratosthenes(11)` to see the difference; 10 is not a prime number and is being filtered out.